# Using Devexpress Export Control with Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, devexpress, aspxgridview

I use [Devexpress](http://www.devexpress.com) ASP.NET component.

My question is; Can i use [Devexpress Exporting Code](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/Exporting/Exporting.aspx) with only Devexpress Gridview ? Is there any way using vith normal [Gridview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx) ?

For example;

I use this exporting code;

```
protected void btnPdfExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        gridExport.WritePdfToResponse();
    }
```

with Devexpress Gridview;

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="grid">
</dx:ASPxGridView>
```

Is there any way to use same exporting code with normal `Gridview` ?

```
<asp:gridview id="grid">
</asp:gridview>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ASPxGridViewExporter uses the XtraPrinting Library to export the grid content to different formats.  Unfotunately, XtraPrinting Library does not know about the standard GridView and thus cannot export it.

Comment: Also how can i learn which method uses which namespace in DexExpress?

Comment: Hmm, generally, you can search for a method in the documentation, available online at: http://documentation.devexpress.com/.  Also, you can force VS to resolve the fully quialified class name for you.  This command is invoked by the  ALT+SHIFT+F10 shortcut.

Comment: @DevExpress Team I need your help :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895289/total-of-groupsummary-to-totalsummary-in-devexpress

Comment: oops, I missed the question :)

Comment: @DevExpress Another need help for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932891/calculating-a-aspxgridview-column-in-devexpress :))