# Total of GroupSummary to TotalSummary in DevExpress

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview, subtotal

In my `ASPxGridView`,

I getting total simply `IPOTEK` column in footer with this code;

```
<TotalSummary>
<dx:ASPxSummaryItem FieldName="IPOTEK" SummaryType="SUM" ShowInGroupFooterColumn="IPOTEK" DisplayFormat="n0" />
</TotalSummary>
```

And i getting average value of `IPOTEK` column when i grouping in Group's footer.

```
<GroupSummary>
 <dx:ASPxSummaryItem FieldName="IPOTEK" SummaryType="AVERAGE" ShowInGroupFooterColumn="IPOTEK" DisplayFormat="n0" />
</GroupSummary>
```

Everything is OK. For example when i grouping with, it looks like this; (`IPOTEK` column is starting **109.827**)

[image]

What i want is; in `TotalSummary`, only total of `GroupSummary` values for `IPOTEK` column.

Rigth now, for this data adding `TotalSummary` value `109.827` * `3` = `329.481` (GroupSummary * 3)

What i want, for this data adding only and only `GropupSummary` value to `TotalSummary`.

How can i do that?

Best Regards, Soner

Comment: Am I right in my assumption that you want the TotalSummary to be calculated as a sum of group summaries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there is no a straightforward solution to this task.  I see two alternatives:

1)  use a [custom summary](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument3762) for the footer summary and at the stage of the DevExpress.Data.CustomSummaryProcess.Finalize try to run through all group rows, obtain the corresponding summary values and sum them.  To run through group rows, use the following code:

```
protected void ASPxGridView1_CustomSummaryCalculate(object sender, DevExpress.Data.CustomSummaryEventArgs e) {
    if(e.SummaryProcess == DevExpress.Data.CustomSummaryProcess.Finalize) { 
        ASPxGridView grid = sender as ASPxGridView;
        double total = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < grid.VisibleRowCount; i++) 
            if(grid.IsGroupRow(i)) 
                total += Convert.ToDouble(grid.GetGroupSummaryValue(i, grid.GroupSummary[0]));
        e.TotalValue = total;
        e.TotalValueReady = true;
    }
}
```

2) use a label within the column's FooterTemplate container and handle the GridView's PreRender and [BeforeGetCallbackResult](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_BeforeGetCallbackResulttopic) to set this label value.  The value should be calculated using the code above.

I hope, this helps.

**UPDATE**

why are using this code:

```
if (grid.IsGroupRow(7))
```

7 is a visibleRowIndex, you should pass the i parameter there

Comment: I try your first alternative. Normally when i select TotalSummary for IPOTEK column, gettin 3.861.819 value. But when i try your code getting resutl 21.317.855. It should be around 1.800.000. Maybe this code adding all rows value to total right? I want only one value adding total in one group

Comment: In red square is *IPOTEK* subtotal but it's same next subtotal http://i.imgur.com/IR0nO.png

Comment: IPOTEK column's visibleindex is 7.

Comment: OK. You are right! Bur i change grid.GroupSummary[1] because IPOTEK group summary is second. And problem solved. Thank you very much DevExpress Team !