# Calculating a ASPxGridview Column in DevExpress

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I have a `ASPxGridview` (Normally 21 column but i just want process 4 column).

[image]

Every column has a decimal value.
`MV_EDDIE` column is empty.

What i want is, calculating programmaticly  ,`MV_EDDIE` columns is `RISK_EUR - (IPOTEK + MV_BERND)` only in `GroupSummary` and `TotalSummary`.

For example; 
If

```
RISK_EUR = 100
IPOTEK = 40
MV_BERND = 50
```

Then `MV_EDDIE` column should be 100 - (40 + 50) = 10

How can i do that?

**NOTE**: I have a `Sql` like this

```
SELECT A.HESAP_NO, A.TEKLIF_NO1 || '/' || A.TEKLIF_NO2 AS TEKLIF,
            A.MUS_K_ISIM, A.RISK,
            (CASE WHEN A.DOVIZ_KOD = 21 THEN 'EUR' WHEN A.DOVIZ_KOD = 2 THEN 'USD' WHEN A.DOVIZ_KOD = 1 THEN 'TL' END) AS DOVIZ,
            ROUND(KRISK_CV(A.TEKLIF_NO1, A.TEKLIF_NO2,A.DOVIZ_KOD,:TAR),2) AS RISK_EUR,
            NVL(IPOTEK(A.HESAP_NO, :TAR),0) AS IPOTEK, 
            ROUND(SUM(M_V(A.TEKLIF_NO1, A.TEKLIF_NO2,:TAR)),2) AS MV_BERND,
            ROUND(SUM(MV_EX(A.TEKLIF_NO1, A.TEKLIF_NO2,:TAR)),2) AS MV_EDDIE, 
            (CASE WHEN ROUND(SUM(MV_K(A.TEKLIF_NO1, A.TEKLIF_NO2,:TAR)),2) &lt; 0 THEN 
            ROUND(SUM(MV_EX(A.TEKLIF_NO1, A.TEKLIF_NO2,:TAR)),2) ELSE  
            ROUND(SUM(MV_K(A.TEKLIF_NO1, A.TEKLIF_NO2,:TAR)),2) END) AS MV_KASKO,
           B.TARIH, GGUNK(A.TEKLIF_NO1,A.TEKLIF_NO2,:TAR) AS GUN
            FROM S_TEKLIF A, TMP_TAKIP B 
            WHERE A.HESAP_NO = B.HESAP 
            --AND A.HESAP_NO = 316
            AND A.RISK &gt; 0 
            GROUP BY B.TARIH, A.HESAP_NO, A.TEKLIF_NO1 || '/' || A.TEKLIF_NO2 ,
            A.MUS_K_ISIM, GGUNK(A.TEKLIF_NO1,A.TEKLIF_NO2,:TAR),
            A.RISK, A.DOVIZ_KOD,KRISK_CV(A.TEKLIF_NO1, A.TEKLIF_NO2,A.DOVIZ_KOD,:TAR)
            ORDER BY 3
```

**NOTE 2**: I can solve this problem changing my sql query, but i don't want it. My query is complicated already. I don't want change it. Because of that, i want to solve it programmaticly ..

**EDIT**: I want calculate it only `GroupSummary` and `TotalSummary`. Not other row.

Comment: How are you loading the data for your datasource and what type is your datasource? If it's a datatable then you can use a column expression, Let me know and I can give you an example.

Comment: @TBohnen.jnr I load with *SqlDataSource*. Is there a column expression in SqlDataSource?

Comment: There is a column expression on DataTable that is perfect for this, will have a quick look to see if you can use this on sqlDataSource

Comment: I just use ASPxGridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1; and ASPxGridView1.DataBind();... Can you give an example?

Comment: As far as I know you can't actually add or access the data of a sql data source directly, if you don't want to change your code too much I would suggest you make the change to the sql, otherwise let me know and I will give you an example of how to do it with a datatable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone consider the answer i found it.

```
protected void ASPxGridView1_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      GridViewDataTextColumn colTotal = new GridViewDataTextColumn();
      colTotal.Caption = "Total";
      colTotal.FieldName = "Total";
      colTotal.UnboundType = DevExpress.Data.UnboundColumnType.Decimal;
      colTotal.VisibleIndex = ASPxGridView1.VisibleColumns.Count;
      colTotal.PropertiesTextEdit.DisplayFormatString = "n0";
      ASPxGridView1.Columns.Add(colTotal);

  }

protected void ASPxGridView1_CustomUnboundColumnData(object sender, ASPxGridViewColumnDataEventArgs e)
  {
      if (e.Column.FieldName == "Total")
      {
          decimal risk = Convert.ToDecimal(e.GetListSourceFieldValue("RISK"));
          decimal mv = Convert.ToDecimal(e.GetListSourceFieldValue("MV_BERND"));
          decimal ipotek = Convert.ToDecimal(e.GetListSourceFieldValue("IPOTEK"));


          e.Value = risk - mv - ipotek;
      }

  }
```

Comment: Hi Soner, you've found the solution I would use myself for this task :)

Comment: Hi Dev, in this time, i have a lot of question for you. Be ready :)