# GridViewDataTextColumn- Calculate multiple of values of three TextBoxes

Tags: javascript, devexpress

I am having 3 GridViewDataTextColumn to which i want to perform the multiplication of the value and stored in the another GridViewDataTextColumn automatically using javascript.

Comment: I think you should do it on HtmlRowPrepared event of the ASPxGridview. It is looking little tricky to do calculation at client side..

Comment: can u tell me how to do that on  HtmlRowPrepared event of the ASPxGridview? @NiranjanKala

Comment: I have added references in answer..

Answer (score 0):

Source - [ASPxGridView - How do I add a column has the total sum of each row](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q572654)

> Please examine the following code examples that illustrates how to
>   accomplish a similar task in the ASPxGridView control:
>
> [How to sum the values of bound and unbound columns and calculate the
>   total value on the client side with sorting, paging and dragging
>   columns](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/E4848.aspx) [How to sum values of bound and unbound columns and
>   calculate a total value on the client side](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/E2961.aspx)

References:
[ASPxGridView - How to get another column value in the HtmlDataCellPrepared event handler](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q425117)
[Calculating a ASPxGridview Column in DevExpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932891/calculating-a-aspxgridview-column-in-devexpress)
[ASPxGridView - How to add a calculated column](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q416750)